# SwiftMailgun how to add a variable to bodyHTML

Tags: swift

I am using SwiftMailgun library to send email in an app that I am working on and in the bodyHTML I want to add variable to it. I want to replace the 00432 with the resetToken that I am getting from the database but I am having challenges in doing so

```
            //getting the resetToken from response
            let resetToken = jsonData.value(forKey: "token") as! String?
            print(resetToken!)

            let mailgun = MailgunAPI(apiKey: "c0c5741e8ef55e9b2307e137ae5b3e92-c1fe131e-add76801", clientDomain: "sandbox732ceb9922894a27beeabb106146127b.mailgun.org")

            mailgun.sendEmail(to: self.emailAddress.text!, from: "HellooFood Account Password Reset <HellooFood@HellooFood.com>", subject: "HellooFood Account Password Reset", bodyHTML: "Hi there <br> We heard that you lost your password, but dont worry! You can use the code below to reset your password within the next day.<br> <b>00432</b><br>Enter the code in the reset password field to reset your password. <br><br>If this mail is a mistake. just ignore it and nothing will happen.<br>If you are not the one who requested the Password Reset Contact us as soon as possible. <br><br>Thanks  HellooFood") { mailgunResult in

                if mailgunResult.success{

                    //switching the screen
                    let goToResetVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Reset")
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(goToResetVC, animated: false)
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss(withDelay: 1.6)

                }else{

                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No internet connection", message: "Check your data or wifi and try again", preferredStyle: .alert)

                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .destructive, handler: nil))
                    //alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

                    self.present(alert, animated: true)
                }

            }
```

Thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

**Template literals**
That's the answer you shouldn't have a long string like that in the first place.

to create a template literal use the backtick quotes: ``
Using the new quotes you can just press enters in your js.
and when adding a variable u use the following syntax ${}

***E.G.***

```
let token = "123432";
let bodyHTML = `This is text for the mail sent with the ${token} id`
```

This will print:
`This is text for the mail sent with the 123432 id`

Comment: @elhajoui please this is not js this is Swift and syntax ${} is not working

Comment: Oh sorry my bad i can remove my post

Comment: I just find the answer... It is simple string interpolation. It never crossed my mind

Comment: Happy that you found your answer!